# Symfony 2.8 : Rendering Controller (Form Errors Not Showing UP)

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I have an issue trying to render a controller which returns a template with formView.

I understood about the **sub-request**, but I am having difficult time to show any kind of errors.

I think the problem is that after it sees the form is **invalid** it **redirectsToRoute** and it looses the **POST** Request.

If I don't say **redirectTo** it just renders the view.

**base.html.twig**

```
 {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Utility:renderSignUpWizard'), {request: app.request}) }}
```

**Utility Controller**

```
   /**
     * @Route("/registration/wizard/", name="registration.wizard")
     */
    public function renderSignUpWizardAction(Request $request)
    {
        /** @var $user User */
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(SignUpWizardType::class, $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            // save changes to user
            $this->persistAndSave($user);

            // redirect to profile
            return $this->redirectToRoute('profile');
        }
        else if($form->isSubmitted() && !$form->isValid())
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
        }

        return $this->render('partials/signup-wizard.html.twig', array
        (
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you could show the twig file where you put the form I could have given a clearer answer. Check the twig file you tell your controller to render and add the following:

Simple way to generate your form(doesn't include errors):

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Add:

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}
```

if you want erors for a specific field:

```
{{ form_errors(form.name) }}
```